# string copy using pointer as a argument of function.

Tags: c, arrays, string, function, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
void stringcopy(char *, char *);

int main(void) 
{

   char *a="akash";
   char *b;
   stringcopy(a,b);
   printf("%s",b);//why this is null? 
   return 0;
   }
 void  stringcopy(char*a,char*b)
{
     b=a;
     printf("%s\n",b);// it is not null
}
```

> Blockquote
>   in a function stringcopy ,i am getting output right. but after call i am getting null in main.why 
>       it is happening?please explain?

Comment: http://ideone.com/OHVEpw

Comment: In main, you won't see the change, as you are only changing `b` in `stringcopy` in the scope of `stringcopy`

Comment: I guess it happens because in the stringcopy function the function parameters are copied. So u need to pass a pointer to a pointer to modify them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work after `stringcopy` returns, because in C function arguments are passed by value, so `b` will remain unmodified (assignment was made on local copies of `a` and `b`). It is only modified within function. Read about [call stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack).

Pass addresses of `a` and `b` to `stringcopy` and dereference them inside function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void stringcopy(char**, char**);

int main(void) 
{
   char *a = "akash";
   char *b;
   stringcopy(&a, &b);
   printf("%s\n",b);
   return 0;
}

void  stringcopy(char** a,char** b)
{
     *b = *a;
     printf("%s\n", *b);
}
```

Note that this will only make `b` to point to the memory region where string literal `"akash"` is stored, so that's not exactly copying string.

Comment: This fixes one major OP problem, but a weakness remains.  `a` points to a `const char *`.  The suggested `stringcopy()` results in `char *b` also pointing to the same `const char *`.  In this snippet, no big deal though.